# Trying to create a trigger when when supply is at or below 20

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

This is my first attempt at creating a trigger in SQL server 2008.

I want to print a message to the console when the supply of each category is at or below 20. I think I'm somewhere close but I want to be able to print out which category (CategoryName) is at or below 20 and if there is more than 1 category that is at or below 20 list each of them, how can I do this?

```
/* use the pond_tank database just created */
USE PondTank;
GO

/* Notify user when category stock is running at or below 20 */
CREATE TRIGGER CategoryStockLow
ON dbo.Category
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
IF (SELECT COUNT(SupplyNumber) FROM dbo.Category) <= 20
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Category Supply is running at or below 20%'
    END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need to print this out only for the category being inserted/updated/deleted.   Within a scope of the trigger you have access to two tables "inserted" & "deleted" that can provide you with the record(s) that are being acted upon.   Code below should help you

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.CategoryStockLow_trg
ON dbo.Category
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @output VARCHAR(max)
    SELECT @output += 'Category Supply is running at or below 20% for ' + CategoryName + CHAR(13)
    FROM Category 
    WHERE CategoryName in(
        SELECT CategoryName FROM deleted
        UNION 
        SELECT CategoryName FROM inserted)
    GROUP BY CategoryName
    HAVING COUNT(*) <=20

    IF(LEN(@output) > 0)
        print @output
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't shown your schema, I suspect you would want `SUM()` not `COUNT()`:

```
IF (SELECT SUM(SupplyNumber) FROM dbo.Category) <= 20
```